# How do I determine the encoding used in an ASP.NET MVC Post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unicode, utf-8

I need to read data from an MVC POST but want to make sure that I read the POST data in the correct encoding.

So far in my programming history (and in most code I've seen) people assume UTF8.

I'd like to prevent any encoding issues and ensure that my encoder matches what the client is POSTing.

Question

- Is this necessary?
- How do I get the correct encoder for an ASP.NET MVC form POST?

Comment: •Is this necessary?  I would say no

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the HttpRequest.ContentEncoding property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Does that mean that Request.ContentEncoding.GetDecoder() will always give me the right decoder?

Comment: I wonder if there is any code-quality utility that will scan for use of an encoder that isn't Request.ContentEncoding.GetDecoder(), and flag it a an error

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the correct encoder for an ASP.NET MVC form POST?

Browsers don't actually send identification of what encoding the entity body is when submitting a form, so the `ContentEncoding` property is unlikely to tell you anything useful.

Usually it is enough to serve all pages as UTF-8. Then the browser will use UTF-8 to submit forms from those pages, so it's safe to assume UTF-8. Exceptions:

1. if you are worried about the user going to their browser's View->Encoding menu and changing it (this is very unlikely unless you have messed up the encoding already);
2. if you expect other people to be doing cross-site form submissions to your site, and you can't guarantee what encoding their pages will be using.

In principle you should be able to fix these cases by including the attribute `accept-charset="utf-8"` in your form tag. Unfortunately IE handles this wrong and only submits as UTF-8 if there are characters in the form that can't be represented in the current page's encoding. There are two ways to fix this; you can use one or both:

1. include a hidden input whose value contains a character that is not included in any non-UTF encoding (the Unicode snowman U+2603 is a traditional choice);
2. include a hidden input with `name="_charset_"`, which the browser can fill in with the name of the encoding it is using when submitted. This is an IE hack that has been adopted by some other recent browsers.

Comment: Could an encoding mismatch ever result in a security issue?  see http://security.stackexchange.com/q/46333/396

Answer (score 0):

When the browser is set to use a non utf-8 character set, we noticed MVC and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax mostly take care of encoding. But not when you are posting text values in a querystring.

This results in illegal unicode characters:

```
$.post("/Question/Save?Text=очень");
```

This works for non utf-8 charset:

```
var formValues = {};
formValues.Text = "очень";
$.ajax("/Question/Save", { type: "POST", data: formValues });
```

(Tested in Chrome and IE11)